# AutoMapper - Mapping expressions from two sources causes exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, expression, automapper

I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.0, Automapper 6.2.2

In my project I want AutoMapper to allow mapping from two sources to one destination (and the opposite). Please consider the following model:

```
class UserA {
 public CustomerId {get;set;}
 public CustomerName {get;set;}
}

class UserB {
 public CustomerId {get;set;}
 public CustomerEmail {get;set;}
}

class UserViewModel{
 public Id {get;set;}
 public CustomerName {get;set;}
 public CustomerEmail {get;set;}   
}
```

My AutoMapper Profile is configured as follows:

```
CreateMap<UserA , UserViewModel>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.Id , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerID))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName)).ReverseMap()
             .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());

CreateMap<UserB , UserViewModel>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.Id , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerID))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerEmail , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerEmail )).ReverseMap()
             .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());
```

I've a Rest API which expose UserViewModel and should allow to filter results based on either Id, CustomerName or CustomerEmail. The API consumer should not be aware to which entity CustomerName and CustomerEmail belongs to.

I've created a service method:

```
public override async Task<IEnumerable<UserViewModel>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<UserViewModel, bool>> filter = null, Expression<Func<IQueryable<UserViewModel>, IOrderedQueryable<UserViewModel>>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
```

Now I would like to map both parameters

```
Expression<Func<UserViewModel, bool>> filter
Expression<Func<IQueryable<UserViewModel>, IOrderedQueryable<UserViewModel>>> orderBy
```

To

```
Expression<Func<UserA, bool>> filterA
Expression<Func<IQueryable<UserA>, IOrderedQueryable<UserA>>> orderByA

Expression<Func<UserB, bool>> filterB
Expression<Func<IQueryable<UserB>, IOrderedQueryable<UserB>>> orderByB
```

but mapping gives me an exception, when I apply a filter with UserEmail and want to map to UserA. I would like AutoMapper to ignore all parts of expression  that are configure Ignored.

ie.

```
var filterA= Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<UserA, bool>>>(filter);
```

Gives an exception

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: memberInfo

AutoMapper.Internal.ReflectionHelper.GetMemberType(MemberInfo memberInfo)
AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Expression1`1 -> Expression`1
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1`1[[System.Func`2[[Cluster.Users.ViewModel.UserDetailViewModel, Cluster.User, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] -> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`2[[Cluster.Model.SimsModel.UserDetail, Cluster.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]

lambda_method(Closure , Expression1<Func<UserDetailViewModel, bool>> , Expression<Func<UserDetail, bool>> , ResolutionContext )
```

The final problem is UserA and UserB are stored in two separate databases, therefore they are fetched from the DB using two different db contexts.

**Edit**

I've also tried Automapper projection which seems to be fetching data correctly, but it separately fetch all related collections (In my question I've provided a simplified model to better explain the problem, but real Entities have dependant one-to-many relations). 
The other problem is it also breaks the architecture a little bit as I would have to GetQueryable() from repository and build the query in the service, instead of passing all parameters to repository directly.

```
var usersA = _readOnlyRepository.GetQueryable<UserA>().ProjectTo<UserViewModel>().Where(filter).ToList();
var usersB = _readOnlyRepository.GetQueryable<UserB>().ProjectTo<UserViewModel>().Where(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: Instead use for the resolve `opts.ResolveUsing` and make a single map

Comment: How would it help?

Comment: You have to combine these two models in a single one then map using the unified view model.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not helpful at all. How would you like to map two class sources to one using single mapping?

Comment: Then create a new class, combinding both sources. It logically not correct to map from mutliple sources.

Comment: You are wrong. Automapper supports flattening and mapping from multiple sources. What's the leverage of using Automapper at all if you suggest creating an intermediate class and fill it up manually. It makes no sense.

Comment: Try `.ReverseMap()`.

Comment: ReverseMap() is there in the Automapper profile snippet